# What are the values of the crossorigin = “use-credentials” attribute in html for?

Tags: html, web, attributes

can you tell me what "use-credentials" value is for. I know that this is for sending cookies, ssl sertifikat and HTTP authentication data, but I don’t understand why I should send my data. I can use "anonymous", but what's the point of using the "use-credentials" values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can use "anonymous"

Maybe you can, but maybe the resource you are requesting requires authentication and authorization so you have to send a cookie to get it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have one question :) the cookie contains information about sites where I login(for example I login in google, facebook etc.):

Comment: The cookie contains whatever was stored in that cookie.

Comment: that is, when I log in to the site from which I will download my file, it will use this particular data?(sorry I'm a beginner in programming).

Comment: The cookie still contains what was stored in the cookie. I've no idea what the hypothetical site you're talking about might have stored in it.

Comment: for example- I open "www.site1.com" site. In there, there is one link for download image, and that image located in "www.site2.com",  and  the "www.site2.com" require authentication for download. the question is this- What data will use that site from my cookie?

Comment: Still whatever data was stored in the cookie in the first place. Please read an introduction to cookies instead of asking me to write one. The world doesn't need another one.